# Float date conversion

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, matplotlib, pandas

I'm creating two same date ranges using Pandas and Matplotlib. After conversion of numpy.float64 to Pandas timestamp I have 1 minute diff - why?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt

dstart = dt.date(2013,12,5)
dend = dt.date(2013,12,10)

d1 = pd.date_range(dstart, dend, freq='H')
d2 = mdates.drange(dstart, dend, dt.timedelta(hours=1))

print d1[2]
print pd.Timestamp(mdates.num2date(d2[2]))
```

And get the result:

```
2013-12-05 02:00:00
2013-12-05 02:01:00.504201+00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that also the length of both ranges are not the same:

```
>>> len(d1)
121
>>> len(d2)
120
```

I think this can be considered as a bug in `mdates.drange`, but the error is introduced because you are using `dates` as input and no `datetimes` (which is what the docstring also says it should be). At least, `mdates.drange` could check for this I think.
When using `datetimes`, it is as expected:

```
In [50]: dstart = dt.datetime(2013,12,5)
In [51]: dend = dt.datetime(2013,12,10)
In [52]: d1 = pd.date_range(dstart, dend, freq='H')
In [53]: d2 = mdates.drange(dstart, dend, dt.timedelta(hours=1))
In [54]: print d1[2]
2013-12-05 02:00:00

In [55]: print pd.Timestamp(mdates.num2date(d2[2]))
2013-12-05 02:00:00+00:00
```

Notice that the length is still different, because `mdates.drange` produces a half open interval (so `dend` not included) while `pd.date_range` produces a closed interval.

---

The technical explanation of why this fails is that the calculation in `mdates.drange` of the end value of the range goes wrong because of the `date` (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/dates.py#L361). The end value would be in your case in hours, but by using a date, the hours are neglected, and a wrong interval is created.

Comment: Thank you! But is there any reason why    dt.date(2013,12,5) is not equal to dt.datetime(2013,12,5)

Comment: The first is a `date` object, and the second is a `datetime` object. And `date` objects have no information about hours, minutes etc.